# Javascript counter with decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wmaftobx/2/)

It's a simple javascript function that counts up to a set number.

Is it possible to do this counting but with one decimal place as well

So it count 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.

```
    function startCounter(){
        $('.counter').each(function (index) {
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    }   

    startCounter();
```

Comment: `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now)/10);` does the trick..

Comment: @Kenney - Then it won't count to 92.2, but only to 9.2.

Comment: Indeed.. but I'm sure you can figure out multiplying the `Counter` value by 10 fixes that, right? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Update

Check for the size of mantissa by using .split().

```
var size = $(this).text().split(".")[1] ? $(this).text().split(".")[1].length : 0;
```

and then use that to estimate .toFixed() size like this

```
$(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size));
```

Here is an updated demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/wmaftobx/13/**

---

Instead of `Math.ceil(now)` use [`.toFixed(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) like this

```
parseFloat(now).toFixed(1)
```

Here is the updated demo **https://jsfiddle.net/wmaftobx/6/**

Comment: That was a neat fiddle, I have a quick question, I noticed you used the `prop` function. I thought the `prop` worked only with boolean values and how come the value does not show up in the DOM?

Comment: This is really nice way of doing it. Is it possible to to count with the decimal place if it there but then not when it not there. Here the second number doesn't have a decimal place but the function still shows it when counting - https://jsfiddle.net/wmaftobx/9/

Comment: @ttmt, try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmaftobx/12/, it is an extension of Dhiraj's solution.

Comment: @Lordbalmon: .prop() works with different types of values. I did not explicitly use .prop(). I just used what was provided by OP

Comment: @Lordbalmon: If a property is being set using .prop() and if it is a standard property like (class, tagName, nodeName, etc.) it would reflect in the DOM otherwise it would just be stored internally.

Comment: @Dhiraj, thank you for the explanation and the update is even cooler.. too bad I can't upvote it again :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did: Replace `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now))` with `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now)/10)` and `Counter: $(this).text()` by `Counter: $(this).text()*10`. It will increment by tenths. For each additional decimal place divide or multiply by 10.

Comment: But it no longer counts to 92.2 but instead to 9.22 (rounded to 9.2).

Comment: Oops, you're right. I read too hastily and missed the part where you changed the initialization of `Counter`. +1 to you. :)

Answer (score 3):

change one line..

```
$(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
```

to

```
$(this).text(Math.round( now * 10 ) / 10);
```

[**Here is a fiddle with the updated code**](https://jsfiddle.net/wmaftobx/7/)